# Can I block incoming calls by prefix to avoid spammers?

Tags: spam-prevention, google-voice, voip

I get a lot of spam calls to my Google Voice number. The spammer spoofs a phone number that starts with the same area code and prefix as my number. The last 4 digits are always different so blocking it doesn't have any effect. I basically now know that if the incoming number shares my prefix, it must be spam.

Is there a way to block all calls from (xxx) xxx-****?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly use the Google Contacts "Import" feature to create a single contact listing all 10000 phone numbers that share that 6-digit prefix. There might be a phone number limit, if so try making 10 contacts with 1000 numbers each (or 100 with 100) - then group them and block the group.

You can see the correct format for a contact with multiple numbers if you create one manually and then export it to a file.

The easiest way to build the list of numbers would probably be with Excel.  If you list the numbers 0 through 9999 in column A, you can concatenate them all together in column B, then copy the value from the last row of column B. The column B formula (starting in B2) would be something like this:

```
=CONCATENATE(B1," ::: 800-555-",A2)
```

Comment: This sounds like a good approach, if not cumbersome...but maybe it would solve the problem. I wonder if this many contacts would cause an issue with my phone, which would probably try to sync all of them.

Comment: Very good question. I did test the export/import, but the rest is theory (I did not verify what would happen when you add 10k new numbers to your phone)